# How to proceed after being threatened and treated poorly by university faculty after reporting physical assault?

Tags: united-states, legal-issues, harassment, discrimination

I’m an Indian PhD student at a mathematics department in the US. A few months back, I was deliberately shoulder-bumped for a few seconds by another PhD student. This student had previously chased me across the department (literally), invaded my personal space, and stared me down. I asked to change offices, which is usually a routine affair, but a faculty member stepped in to prevent this. I had to remain in close proximity with this guy, who continued to act in passive-aggressive ways.

After the shoulder bumping, I threatened to go to campus police. The aforementioned faculty member responded (in writing) saying: “There is no proof of this ever happening; I can’t prevent you from going to the campus police, but be warned that both of you can get expelled."

Also prior to this, I had reported several racist incidents from another student. A few example quotes are:

- "you fucking Indians" in a very threatening tone,
- "don’t tell me you fucking Indians count so fast,"
- "You Indians and Chinese are taking over,"
- or in a mocking tone: "It’s funny there is racism in your country."

When I showed this faculty member documentation of these events, he wrote to me in an email: "I don’t agree with your assessment that there is anything racist in these incidents." He also said the racist PhD student was "special" (though there is no written evidence of him saying this).

Another teaching faculty member had been similarly racist. He said things like:

- "I was scared to come here initially because I thought I would have to learn Hebrew",
- "I'm so white I'll never be mistaken for an Italian who gets mistaken for a terrorist when doing Math on a plane"
- Telling a room full of Chinese students and a couple of Indian students: "If you speak in Mandarin or Hindi in the corridors you will get into serious trouble, like some Chinese students and postdocs from the past who were speaking Chinese in the corridors and it created a lot of mistrust and there were very serious complaints" (no-one else has ever heard of these incidents).

Further, he physically intimidated me and barged into my office at one point. The faculty member said he had not done anything inappropriate (again no written evidence of this specifically). In fact he said, it is commendable and shows the teaching faculty member is very socially aware and aware of his white privilege.

I would not have necessarily made an issue out of this again, but I recently received a threatening letter from the dean and this faculty member. This letter warned that I could be "withdrawn" and stated that I wouldn't be allowed to defend a thesis right away. I replied saying "Are you sure you want to take such a tone after the murder of George Floyd?" Their reply was: "If you keep speaking like this, we will 'withdraw' you."

How should I proceed after these incidents? I'm particularly interested in legal recourse (though the incidents mentioned may be hard to prove in a court of law, although I have these written emails from our faculty member).

Comment: **Moderator’s notice:** This question had already been posted, was deleted and re-posted as per [this new policy](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4762/7734). The existing answer was merged here. In this respect, everything is fine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112944/discussion-on-question-by-laputalanglang-threatened-and-treated-poorly-by-facult). Comments after this one must request clarification or seek improvements to the post only; please see [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4230/why-do-the-moderators-move-comments-to-chat-and-how-should-i-behave-afterwards).

Comment: What sort of university is it? Is it public or private? Can you give the state?

Comment: Have you reported all this to the nearest Indian consulate and asked if they could help?

Comment: @Acccumulation: this is a private university; in Massachusetts.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I did speak with the nearest Indian Consulate a few months back, when I had not received this threatening letter. They basically said they can't do anything about alleged incidents. I'm not sure their reply would be any different after getting this threatening letter.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: There is no faculty Dean in our university, and the threats were already coming from the Dean of the so called Graduate school.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have irrefutable evidence of this harassment, you might want to go to the press. The university newspaper and/or local or even national newspapers. Your life will be turned upside down, but maybe it will protect future students of color from this harassment.

Comment: are the emails mentioned above from this faculty member irrefutable evidence of illegal behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is well-known evidence of much worse harassment against people like OP by professors at many US universities, and nobody cares. People joke about it. In the US system, there simply is no recourse for people like him.

Comment: wow, that's really sad to hear. do you have any specific instances in mind?

Comment: @laputalanglang Of course, but the policy that deleted your question yesterday would also delete my comment. So here's a better framing that would avoid deletion: try asking the folks suggesting solutions if they've _ever_ seen such solutions actually work for international students like yourself. They will universally say something like, no, but I just assumed that was how the system was _supposed_ to work.

Comment: A particularly sad example is the newest answer proposing you secretly record the incidents and present the recordings as proof. What would actually happen is that such evidence would be thrown out, and then the legal system would promptly come down on you, because such recording is illegal. That's the system working.

Comment: yes I would not make such a recording. yes, it's true, except for one situation in Duke a couple of years back where there was email evidence of faculty saying things like Chinese students should not speak in the hallways in Chinese. Even then that was objectively less serious than what I'm describing here.

Comment: The admissibility of recorded conversations varies widely by jurisdiction and situation.  You would have to check the relevant laws for your specific state.  That said, this route seems like it would be detrimental to finishing your degree.  At the least you should try to finish before you do this.

Comment: Going to the press is fun for the press, and for all the other people who support general action, but it may completely ruin OP's career. Not good advice without tempering it with getting lawyer's advice and probably professional media advice, too, also to make OP's steps more effective.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I did say that it would turn the OP's life upside down.

Comment: @laputalanglang this doesn't need to be illegal for it to be a scandal/disaster for the university. I'm not a lawyer, so I can't speak to the legality of the faculty's behavior. There probably is a faculty guide that described the code of conduct. This almost certainly violates that code of conduct. Also, in cases like this, there are probably other people of color in the department who have been mistreated. If one person comes forward, others might find the courage to do so as well.

Comment: @knzhou "the system is working" is a cynical, inappropriate response on the ban of secret recording. The ban of secret recording is perfectly justified: its purpose is simply the protection of individual's and possibly company rights, otherwise no-one is safe to have a confidential conversation and you will get an overall paranoid society. The law has its justification, and given that the US already has very lax data protection laws (compared to Europe and especially Germany) it is a perfectly sensible law. Or remove all citizen's rights, habeascorpus etc. because they also help criminals?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, I believe the intent of the cynical comment about "the system is working" is to point out that whistle-blowers often face (illegal) retribution for exposing abuses. That retribution is often framed as punishment for some other infraction (in this case illegal recording). Sometimes that infraction is used as an excuse to ignore the whistle-blower's report.

Comment: @KyleA I believe I quite understood the comment. Every component of the jurisdicial system can be used as a weapon. It is naive to believe that a legal measure introduced for a legitimate reason cannot be abused. It can and it will be abused. It does not make the measure per se illegitimate; it is populistic to insinuate this measure enables abuse. In particular, it is an entirely separate issue from complots of abusive people who will exploit all means to their disposal. Exposing them is hard and OP needs professional legal and possibly media advice, as I said above.

Comment: If you would go for this I would recommend you to find others with the same Problem. One voice might not be enough and it will be your word against the dean...you will probably only loose here. Nevertheless if it is an option you might want to read up on the silence breakers (one of them Celeste Kidd) at the University of Rochester. Its not totally related but the sad outcome was that that Professor is still teaching. So be aware, even such measures might not have the impact you are hoping.

Answer (score 32):

There's a lot to parse here, particularly in the lengthy comments section.  The way I see it is you've got two options:

1. Go outside of the department for help
2. Avoid these conflicts and finish

It seems apparent that the department is not going to help you through this, since you mention both the Dean and the department chair being involved negatively.  If you opt for number one, you should look for school-wide resources, similar to Title IX coordinators for gender issues.  I'm not aware of this being standardized, so you should look through your university's resources.

I think whether you go with option 1 probably depends on how close you are to finishing.  If you're close, and you've been able to work successfully with your advisor, is it possible to minimize, or even cut, all contact with the rest of the department, and just get your degree?  It's hard to swallow injustice, but from a utilitarian point of view, there may not be much to gain by fighting with the people in charge of the department you're in.  Letting bullying by fellow PhD students go unanswered by simply avoiding them galls me, even, and I'm the one giving the advice!  But you should at least weigh the option when considering what's best for you; fighting racism in your department, or escaping with your PhD.

Of course if you're not close to finishing, option two becomes far less viable.  I'm sorry you're in such a toxic environment, and I hope you can finish your degree successfully despite it.  Perhaps some combination of 1 and 2 is possible - it seems sensible to immediately begin avoiding the sources of conflict in your department, even if you do opt to challenge their behavior at a higher level.

Comment: I meant the former departmental chair. the current departmental chair is above these things.

Comment: It is the department chair's job to deal with situations like this.  They don't get to be "above such things".

Comment: The behavior you describe sounds like a clear violation of Title VI of the Civil Rights Act (the same federal law whose Title IX forbids discrimination of the basis of sex).  I recommend discretely approaching the Title IX office for advice.

Comment: I meant to say the current departmental chair is a respectable mathematician, who would never personally stoop low like a couple of these other people.

Comment: @laputalanglang Have you talked to him about this then?

Comment: @TheoreticalMinimum: No I have not had the opportunity to speak with him about this. The thuggery is now emanating from the Dean of the Graduate school.

Comment: @laputalanglang well maybe ou should do that then. On monday, 8 am!! And tell him that this discrimination has to stop or you can't finish your work. Don't make any complaints about individual people in the beginning. Let him ask for names and details.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure he knows of the situation now, although he didn't a month back, I think. If he couldn't do anything about it yet, it probably means it's beyond his control now.

Comment: @laputalanglang Talk to thim. Why are you so reluctant? Before you go to media or elsewhere go to him first.

Comment: Well, he barely replies to emails about talking about Mathematics these days. He has health issues himself and doesn't come to the university. The letter that I got is so diabolically worded that no faculty member here seems willing to take any kind of stance on it.

Comment: @laputalanglang: Please email the department chair and the Title IX office.

Comment: I did talk with the Title IX office, and they emphasized that I had once said I don't want to pursue a case against the grad student who said the racist things; I mentioned a lot of other alleged comments from other people within our department, and they said it's all OK.

Comment: I also don't mention harassment by another teaching faculty member, who doesn't say explicitly offensive things on the fly, but tombs have been written about how lowly she treats international students when it comes to simple teaching responsibilities.

Comment: @laputalanglang: Just to clarify, will the title IX office do anything about it? I think the chair of the department should be informed of your situation.

Comment: There is this Office of equal opportunity manned by one individual. I don't know what she is upto. I think these are all a bunch of clowns. In the end, I remarked to this individual that one serious problem is that I'm a high caste individual, and look at white people in my university as an abominable low caste, and that automatically creates a lot of problems.

Comment: the departmental chair knows the situation well by now, i think, and knows the Dean of Graduate School has taken charge.

Comment: How did the department chair respond? Have you brought this up with him/her?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113216/discussion-between-laputalanglang-and-mehta).

Comment: @dusa, please see my reply in the chat. Caste had been recently added as a protected class by the university.

Comment: @laputalanglang And you think that making caste a protected class gives you the right to practice discrimination against people you view as lower caste? That's some mental gymnastics.

Comment: It was in very poor taste, even as a troll comment. But I was used to often having a poor taste in my mouth while interacting with certain people in this university.

Comment: I hope in the discussion, I could make it clear that I don't actually view white people in my university as a lower caste, or want to look down on lower castes in India. If you need references of Indians who I riled up with my stated support of caste based reservation, or some of my closest friends in college from a non privileged caste, maybe there is a way to get those references.

Comment: Are you trying to say you made these comments sarcastically? If you wrote them the way you did here I would certainly not take them that way, and in that case you are not being treated poorly by HR but rather exactly how you should be treated based on your comments. Sarcasm is very very difficult to convey properly in text.

Comment: After checking his chat text, Apparently he made them sarcastically for the most part, but I say he is looking for trouble with an email like that either way.

Comment: After the murder of George Floyd, there was a questionable document shared to help increase diversity and eviscerate racism; I had commented: "talk about the serious challenge of reverse racism as well", and "cherish and preserve the existing diversity in intellectual and ethical standards", and another Indian PhD student had made a huge post detailing some of his experiences, which if true, were very disturbing as well.

Comment: Was "talk about the serious challenge of reverse racism as well" also meant to be sarcastic, or is it your opinion that reverse racism is a challenge that needs to be addressed? I truly cannot detect when your sarcasm is sarcasm, if it was.

Comment: It was meant to be sardonic. You're not the first person to tell me that I'm a bit inscrutable in this regard.

Comment: @laputalanglang Sardonic speech, sarcasm, etc, **does not come off in text**. It really only ever works with people who know you very well and already know how you think about things. You should never ever ever use this type of language when communicating a serious offense to a responsible individual or group. If you've done so, you have completely undermined your own credibility.

Comment: I also called the teaching faculty member mentioned here a "tenth rate dimwit"; there's like a 30% documentation of his antics here; the ones mentioned here are also shorn of context, so it might come across as very very condescending.

Comment: @laputalanglang I would not take very seriously the comments and complaints of someone who called a teaching faculty a "tenth rate dimwit". Even if the complaints are very serious, that sort of behavior suggests the problem is with the person using that description.

Comment: It could have been seen as a backhanded compliment, if you think about it; in the quality of being a dimwit he is deemed as being tenth rate; so he's doing fine, I guess.

Comment: @laputalanglang No, there is no way to interpret it as anything but an insult. There is no lack of clarity on that point, no matter how much you want to argue it's a joke.

Comment: @laputalanglang I don't know anything about your department besides what you've said here, so I would never agree to that. If **you** think it's garbage, you should leave.

Comment: @Jeff In cases where the bullying behavior involves gaslighting, or any significant power asymmetry, there is often very little one can do except avoid the bully.

Answer (score 15):

Can you get a lawyer? I know the universities give legal advice, but in this case they won't. Can you reach out to Indian communities? Perhaps a lawyer can offer you free services?  1) please go to the International Student Services for guidance. If all fails, 2) please go to HR and talk to them, but remember HR is not your friend, they will most likely try to keep it within the institution. If they cooperate, they will hire external reviewers to get their legal opinion on the case, but it can turn into you against the faculty member/dean and HR might take their side.

This might be stressful for you, but I think you are already living a stressful grad life, if anything at least you can make it right for others. I am sorry you are going through this, no one should! I did my PhD in USA and my university was really a safe place for international students, with a high international student population. International students bring in the most revenue/do most of the research, so if your university has any senses at all, they will try to resolve this. If you are just beginning PhD, I would consider other options as well: other labs, other departments, other universities.

Comment: I spoke with HR a couple of years back , outlining a lot of events happening inside the department, when they told me nothing is wrong. At that time there wasn't even a so called Office of Equal opportunity inside the department. I went and disparaged the people in HR after they refused to do anything, and in fact after they began to threaten me. Afterwards the HR has also played its' part in this.

Comment: Usually I don't think a lawyer is appropriate in cases of student misconduct, but in this case if the dean knows the facts and is threatening retaliation, a lawyer is called for.

Comment: It's not just student misconduct, but also (teaching) faculty misconduct; unless of course you are implying the misconduct is on my part.

Comment: I can't overstate this enough - do not make any legal threats until you retain a lawyer. You can't unring that bell, and a lawyer is very likely to tell you that you have no ground to stand on.

Comment: @laputalanglang "I went and disparaged the people in HR after they refused to do anything" - what do you mean by "disparaged"?

Comment: @CJRD Can you elaborate on why it is likely there is no ground to stand on? I'm not too familiar with US law but in the EU for example, it would be immediately obvious that the conduct was in breach of all sorts of equality laws.

Comment: If there is no proof, and there is no witness, it is a he said she said case, meaning it is one guy's word over other's. Not enough to charge a person guilty. There is the email but it is written between 3rd parties and is not enough to "prove" the bully's acts. If the university had senses, they would open a case and talk to all people involved. Also, are you sure that in EU this would be easier to address? Might depend on the location, but my experience is that EU is light-years behind in racism at workplace and mobbing in general.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs: Last year, when the folks in HR themselves began to say to me that apparently I must be looking for a lawyer, and they are well prepared for it, I went and said let me take the liberty to speak with you in the same disrespectful tone as some of us are spoken to for years on end in the department. And so whatever interaction we were having, I spoke in a disrespectful tone.

Comment: Look, noone should go through what you are going through, but may I suggest you try being less reactive? How can talking disrespectfully to HR people make the situation better? This could be used against you.

Comment: The situation was so beyond the pale already that I didn't think twice about being reactive at that stage. This post or the chat doesn't mention the frothing at the mouth behavior of certain other graduate students, almost treating you like a leper. I had been in a different university in the US prior to here, and the experience was vastly different. In fact, at one point I told them they should try to strive to improve their overall clown show and become like certain other universities.

Comment: This interaction with the HR was prior to the shoulder bumping, the emails from this faculty member, or the abusive disruptive behavior of my former so called advisor which was defended to the hilt by our department.

Comment: @laputalanglang Ok, what you should have done instead is to explain how how you have been talked to, instead of falling in the trap of giving them the rope to hang you by. It's done. Frankly, even if only half of what you say were true, this place is rotten to the core. You won't be anybody's hero by staying and fighting. There is no glory to be gained here. Get out! And go to a place that deserves your company.

Comment: Of course, I started out by being polite, and my first couple of interactions were very polite with HR. I mentioned a lot of the incidents involving our teaching faculty member, but I forget if I mentioned some or all of the incidents I mention here. They replied in email saying there is nothing wrong.  It's after that, that I took a less polite tone, when they began to say you must be looking for a lawyer, etc. and when I began to disparage them.

Comment: It's not just that there were all these issues within our department, the first guy I was working with , who turned into my advisor, was from another university, and I talk about his behavior in the chat.

Comment: @laputalanglang You are quite right to be angry, even very angry. But when HR said you must look for a lawyer, they were probably giving you the correct advice even if, who knows, in a twisted way. In any case, in my experience, they are amongst the worst party to alienate and to turn from neutral to antagonist. Anyway, the options I see, depending on what you want to do, is getting a lawyer, possibly a media adviser, and leave. This is Mordor, you do not want to stay, no matter what.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs See LPLL's additional detail here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/155185/how-to-proceed-after-being-threatened-and-treated-poorly-by-university-faculty-a#comment415958_155158

Comment: @YemonChoi Oops. That does not go down well, not even as joke, irony or sarcasm. That's a CLM. In chess, such a move would have been annotated with "??".

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Back in my days of playing club chess, that's a move that would be punctuated by going to the bar to curse in private. But I digress

Comment: This was exactly what I had written in the very last email to the Title IX office: "Actually a lot of these problems stem from the fact that I'm a high caste individual, and look around in this university and see a dimwitted peasant class that is a natural anathema for me. Do you think that can enable you to take some kind of action?" I did not say 'white people in the university were an abominable lower caste'. The idea was to bark back.

Comment: The context was that this university made headlines by adding caste as a protected class, and thus showed off it's progressive cred.I should mention that in the prior emails, the documentation that I had was huge, and this thread or the chat probably covers at most 30% of everything documented there.

Comment: @dusa: The impression you got from my reply on the chat is that I support the caste system?

Comment: 'I mean, caste should be a protected class' (present tense), 'I have openly advocated for caste based reservation in India and why it is important for it to continue for at least a few generations, and have faced the wrath of some of my friends for saying this' (past tense), then your opinions changed because you have low caste friends and you are cool with them now, but doesn't state your opinion on whether it should be abolished. I am just reading what you wrote.

Comment: One generic advise: When you know you are right, do not ever play in other person's hand by acting wrong. Practice staying calm in situations. Graduate school comes and goes, this advice is for lifetime

Comment: Edit: For anyone reading, OP was trolling them giving them their own medicine, which oh boy, will get him in so much trouble one day.

Comment: Caste should be a protected class, to protect from casteist behavior and casteist slurs; I'm not saying that I support casteism. It's like saying having anti-racism laws perpetuate racism. I view caste based reservation as important to end inequality and casteism in India, and given the social structure of the country in the present and the past, it's important to have it as opposed to reservation based on economic status.

Comment: I was just pointing out the conflict of what you wrote. I am not sure where "openly advocating to preserve it in India" stands with "I have friends from other castes now". If you say you are against it, okay fine, I don't read a strong message e.g. it should be a protected class in US but not in India? What am I supposed to get? I have black friends does not equal to I am anti-racism, for example. Anyway, I edited my comment, my emphasis was on the trolling, and my advice stays.

Comment: I am opposed to the caste system, if it makes it clear now. I believe temporary caste based reservation (as things stand, for at least another couple of generations) is only helping to tackle caste based inequality in India.

Comment: Yes, more clear, definitely. I am not knowledgeable about the temporary preservation part, I don't see why it is necessary, and why the change shouldn't come overnight but I won't pretend to know. It is awkward though, like suggesting a transition of generations instead of giving people equal rights? Anyway derailing the topic.

Comment: In a healthy economic system, taxes work, and there is upward mobility btw.

Answer (score 5):

To me your description sounds like a fully grown mobbing/bullying situation. The conclusion is that I'm afraid your best bet is to get away from there, the sooner the better.

This is not a single misbehaving (harrassing, racist,...) individual or incident who *may* be made to behave themselves, but a whole group who ganged up, including some of your superiors and repeatedly harrass.

In addition to getting away from there for the sake of your own health and academic performance, you should not honor such a department with your work.

- Do you already have a professional network?
- Are there professors from other places whom you trust and who know your work?

=> contact them about openings

- Are there fellow students whom you can trust?
- International student networks?

=> contact them to find out whether the prospective new place is likely better.

- Be *extremely* professional and reticent in describing why you leave. However, make clear that the reason is not lack of academic achievement - you may say that you count on being even more productive in the new environment, though.

  Where I am students can take their *own* thesis work with them when they happen to change university (with some caveats related to employment and employers having rights to work results). I.e., you may be able to use e.g. papers you already published for your thesis at the new university. Ask about this.
- Is there someone to whom you can unburden yourself? Relations, friends, psychological counseling, a religious or spiritual advisor?

---

A few points about mobbing/bullying I picked from [W. Taglieber: Berliner Anti-Mobbing-Fibel (in German) [Berlin Anti-Mobbing leaflet - it is mainly about bullying in school, but many of the points fit with what you describe]](https://www.berlin.de/familie/de/asset/download/asset-1226)

- The victim has basically no possibility to liberate themselves on their own [while staying at there]
- Attacks are wilfully intentional and arbitrary
- Mobbing/bullying is abuse of power
- It will not end on its own
- Sequence of events:

  1. the potential bully looks for weaknesses/sensitivities of the potential victim
  2. Outward characteristics are picked afterwards (ethnicity, hair color, dialect, ... literally *whatever*) to use as pretended "reason"

  IMHO it is important to realize: the chosen victim has no whatsoever chance to avoid the bullying attacks by changing the picked characteristic since that follows after the fact - and can and will be changed arbitrarily. (This goes in particular @Mandrill)
  (Even a characteristic that is not the case with the victim can serve. Say, bullying OP as "Russian" when they're Indian - which signals that the victim is not even worth bothering to label them correctly)
- The victim is in a physiologically stressful situation. This is both a threat to their health and it is likely to hinder their academic performance.
  This is one of the reasons why you need to get away from there!
- Whithin the situation there is *nothing* that the victim can do to reliably stop the situation: normally [in a non-bullying situation] adequate, polite requests to the bully to behave themselves are not sufficient. Strong actions that to gets results are counted as the victim overreacting, i.e. *against* the victim.
  See OP's description for an example.

Also as said above, the attacks are arbitrary and wilful, i.e. the only pattern they reliably follow is that they will happen when a bully (or one of their so-called helpers/followers) thinks the attack will be safe (see OP describing lots of situations where they do not have witnesses who'd stand up) and have impact.

- There is a strong structural component to bullying: organizational structures that allow this to happen.
  Here: those authorities whose duty it would be to prevent or at least stop such bullying have joined the mob.

---

Last but not least: of course this may be genuine racism, i.e. race is the systematic and predictable trigger for the aggression rather than a picked "well-working" characteristic of a chosen victim. IMHO that distinction is rather academic, though: I think the practical possibilities and limitations are the same whether the underlying behaviour is mainly racist or mainly bullying. And for me, both rank as equally bad.

Comment: The letter that I got; if I were to make the contents public, might be disturbing to read.

Answer (score 3):

Could you maybe contact the American Civil Liberties Union and ask them for advice?

https://www.aclu.org/faqs#1_5

I'm not American and have no experience at American universities but these guys are always in the news with cases similar to yours. Maybe someone who knows more about the US system can expand this answer.

Answer (score -3):

Do you have smartphone? Just install app called IP Webcam(I am not sponsoring this, I don't even know the meaning of sponsoring), now follow all procedure set it all up, it works even if your smartphone is locked. It can simply record videos and audios of them. If you can successfully record the incidents and then present them as proof, you are done with your part, let them handle the legal stuff now. Of course as mentioned by one of the answerer, if you are close to finishing your degree, better come home safe and quick! I wish I could help you real quick.

Comment: Not sure, but this could be illegal.

Comment: Oh so if you are being killed you won't try to video them and present it as proof that they were trying to kill you???

Comment: Recording people without their consent is illegal in many states.  I would not recommend this unless you are sure (because you've consulted a lawyer) that you're not breaking the law.  (This is not a criminal case, and they can use any illegality as an excuse to kick you out.)

Comment: Why do you use CCTV cameras then??? Tell me?

Comment: Do you have witnesses?

Comment: Well, I don't know if eye witnesses would be willing to come forwward. I don't think anyone faced crap to the extent I did;  but there have been serious situations in the department in the past involving other international students.

Comment: Veering off-topic, but CCTV cameras are typically used in public places where there is no expectation of privacy (e.g., stores). Recording closed-door conversations and phone calls is a different ball of wax legally (in the US, such rules even vary state by state).

Comment: @Dumb It has to be made clear by signs that CCTV is used. So while you are recorded, you know that you are recorded. No hidden cameras are allowed without information that CCTV is used. So this is much different.

Comment: If you want to record, consult a lawyer. The laws regarding video recording and audio recording vary from state to state in the US. Also, video and audio may have different rules (so CCTV might be allowed in a public hallway, but secretly recording audio of a conversation in that same hallway may be illegal).